# Android: fixed header in top

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

want to have a fixed header on the page but I can not.

I'm doing so.:
code XML [fragment_products.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Headerrrr"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sw_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sw_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtde"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:textColor="#acacac" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA code (FindProductsFragment):

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data
             * */
            String[] sr = { TAG_NAME, TAG_QTDE };
            int[] in = { R.id.name, R.id.qtde };

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), productsList, R.layout.fragment_products, sr, in);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The result is not what I want.

[image result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8z2-iNMzxXbbEpZQ19ldjY1d28/view?usp=sharing)

want to have the fixed header.
any idea how to do?

Answer (score 2):

for a fixed header to put on an specific layout, please follow the following pattern (also i am adding a fixed footer view too) :

```
<!-- Header aligned to top -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layered_bg"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/title_app"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layered_bg"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/footer_text"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You just need to add your views between those 2 and you are ready to go.

Regards,

Comment: you should put your other layout elements between those 2 views. And you should align them just between those 2. That is the way. I am using that way in my applications, and i did not encountered any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I did so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/list_background_pressed"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/title_app"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sw_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sw_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtde"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:textColor="#acacac" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I did not get the result we wanted, looked like this:
 [looked like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8z2-iNMzxXbMHdtLWNCV0x6b0E/view?usp=sharing)

and I want something like this:
[something like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8z2-iNMzxXbS3pCN2w0QVdoSEk/view?usp=sharing)